# Notification starts wrong Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

my problem is: Clicking on a notification message starts the running activity and not the intended activity (BatchActivity in my code); (otherwise put, if mainactivity is running, it returns to that, else the home screen of android starts. it seems to just vanishing the status screen)

It used to work fine, until I knotted a previous notification to it, using same Notification ID, since then the BatchActivity is not started. In debug mode the first line in onCreate is never reached.

I tested it on a Sony Xperia Android device, 4.3, build for target 19.
My code:
...

```
   if (qty>0) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, BatchActivity.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
notification  = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle(passing[0].get(6))
    .setContentText("Subject")
    .setTicker("hihi ho haha")
    .setNumber(qty)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "And more", pIntent).build();  
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification); 
} else {
    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
}
```

...

the notification is updating a previous notification.

Thanx in advance! I am stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comes from the fact, that the system does not assume that only because we pass a new Intent object to the pending intent, we want this new intent object to be delivered and just keeps the old (initial) pending intent alive.

To get the desired semantics, we need to pass a flag to tell the system:

```
PendingIntent pintent = 
   PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

This flag (FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT) tells the system that the old pending intent is no longer valid and it should cancel (=remove) it and then create a fresh one for us. There are more possible flags, which are described on the javadoc page for PendingIntent.

Solution by [Heiko Rupp](http://pilhuhn.blogspot.se/2010/12/pitfall-in-pendingintent-with-solution.html)

Comment: @ mach, that is what I want to do, first message: "beginning work", just information, then ending with an update or removal of the first notification. the updated message should start an activity when clicked upon... qty in my codeis the number of messages found in an asynch task

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your problem. Updated the solution.

Comment: @ mach thanx, works swell now. Clear explanation, seems my working solution was not working after all, In tying message 1 and 2 together the problem was created....

Comment: If it solved the problem please mark it as the correct answer. It will help others too :) Cheers!